# How to Select Data with PHP PDO Prepared Statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is my PHP PDO Prepared Statement, to select and show data, but it is giving a lot of errors.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `info` WHERE tag1 IN ('$tag1','$tag2') $andor tag2 IN ('$tag1','$tag2 ') ORDER BY $sort DESC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $start";
// prepare as you have
$sth = $conn->prepare($sql);
// Bind parameters while executing
$sth->execute(array(
':name'=>$name, 
':tag1'=>$tag1,
':tag2'=>$tag2
));
# Fetch the associate array
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

for($x=0, $n=count($result); $x < $n; $x++){

echo "Name: ".$result[$x]['name']."    ";
}
```

Errors:

> Notice: Undefined variable: movie_name
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 0

Everything is working fine, if I do not use prepared statements.

Comment: man ask one question at a time.. u cant ask same question twice and u did not respond to comments

Answer (score 0):

In order to bind the variables you need to change the query. Instead of "$tag1" use :tag1 and so on.

Regards